# Angular Js Select List Fire Event When Complete

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive, selectlist

I have a select list which I am attempting to fire an event when complete rendering.  I have a link here to my JsFiddle code review.  Thanks in advance... [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/G8S32/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <select ng-options="size as size.name for size in sizes " ng-model="item" ng-change="update()"></select>
     {{item.code}} {{item.name}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.sizes = [ {code: 1, name: 'n1'}, {code: 2, name: 'n2'}];
  $scope.update = function() {
      console.log('77: ' + $scope.item.code, $scope.item.name)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate`<option>` elements by using `ng-repeat` and fire your callback on last item rendered by using directive:

```
myApp.directive('onLastRepeat', function($timeout) {
    return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.$eval(attrs.onLastRepeat);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="size in sizes" value="{{size.code}}" on-last-repeat="yourCallback()">{{size.name}}</option>
</select>
```

There is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/G8S32/406/

**EDIT:**

Solution with called onChange() event when selected option is changed: http://jsfiddle.net/G8S32/408/

Comment: Okay, now add the that the ability to call an event onChange of the select option, then we have a winner!  Interested in seeing your results.  Thus far, thanks.

Comment: @RobertGreen Added. It works as same as in your code.